# How can I selectively load assets in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm noticing that our rails 4.0 app is experiencing loading "lag" when I clear my cache or load the website  in Incognito window. It takes approx. 8 seconds to load the right scroll bar which is far too long!

I'd like to speed up this process, and one idea is to selectively load certain assets only for the "signed in" user and not load these assets for general visitors.

How can we accomplish this? Or if there are other ideas to improve app performance, and solve this loading issue - it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing specifically what is loading slowly, but have you tried something like [this](http://mrjoelkemp.com/2012/04/rails-lazy-loading-of-scripts/) to only load certain scripts?

Comment: It's definitely a good start point to identify who's the responsible of that huge load time. You should be able to point it out by checking the request log, maybe you can paste it here.